# Seek not working - React Native Video Player

Tags: react-native

I want to start a video from the specific time at the time of video load but seek does not work, I don't know why. Please help.

```
onVideoLoad(e) {
   this.videoPlayer.seek(time);
}

<Video
  source={require('../test1.mp4')}
  ref={videoPlayer => this.videoPlayer = videoPlayer}
  onEnd={this.onVideoEnd.bind(this)}
  onLoad={this.onVideoLoad.bind(this)}
  onProgress={this.onProgress.bind(this)}
  paused={paused}
  volume={Math.max(Math.min(1, volume), 0)}
  resizeMode="contain"
  style={styles.videoContainer}/>
```

Comment: By any chance, have you found the solution?